# How to plot multiple boxplot in one graph for R 2020

Tags: r

I have some data, need to make multiple box plots in one graph. For Rstudio 3.6.1, no ggplot. Please use the available packages. The data file is csv, with 740 rows. Here I cut first 20 rows.

```
   Absenteeism.time.in.hours Social.smoker Social.drinker
1                          4             0              1
2                          0             0              1
3                          2             0              1
4                          4             1              1
5                          2             0              1
6                          2             0              1
7                          8             0              1
8                          4             0              1
9                         40             0              1
10                         8             0              0
11                         8             0              1
12                         8             0              1
13                         8             0              1
14                         1             0              1
15                         4             0              1
16                         8             0              1
17                         2             0              1
18                         8             1              1
19                         8             0              0
20                         2             1              0
```

Comment: What's group variable? Sorry, just start to learn R. Here hours is y value, smoker with 0 and 1, drinker with 0 and 1. boxplot with smoker group by 0 and 1, boxplot with drinker group by 0 and 1.

Comment: What version of R are you talking about? R jumped from R-3.6.3 to R-4.0.0 with nothing in between.

Comment: I still don't understand (rstudio is at 1.3, R never had 3.8, ...), but I don't think it matters. You said *"no reshape, no ggplot"* suggesting that you have tried code. What have you tried?

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but there is no justification for it. I've been using R-3.6 and R-4.0 for years with both `reshape2` and `ggplot2` with absolutely no issues, on both windows and linux. So they work. The issues is not that they don't work in general, it's that something with your code or your installation that is not working. Can you explain what you mean by *"don't support"*? (There is version-confusion, too: your ***R*** may be 3.6.1, your ***RStudio*** is not. `R != RStudio`) Please help us help you ... *show us the code* (and all warnings/errors you get).

Comment: > library(reshape2)
Warning message:
package ‘reshape2’ was built under R version 3.6.3 ---------------This what I got after install reshape2, i think it does not support and then remove reshape2. Yes, my Rstudio is 3.6.1, not sure R version. Looks I misunderstand the warning. Reshape2 works with my version?

Comment: > install.packages('ggplot')
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)------------This is what I install ggplot. I think Rstudio not support ggplot.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your original question. Comments can easily be skipped by readers (with similar problems) and hidden by the Stack UI when there are many of them. Thanks!

Comment: That `reshape2` warning is fine, you can ignore that one for now. You probably mean `install.packages("ggplot2")`, the only `ggplot` is a function within the `ggplot2` package ... yep, dizzying/confusing, but it's the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with just using `boxplot`? No `ggplot2`, and that should work in your version, too.

However, it's not unambiguous what you mean by "multiple box plots in one graph". Here three versions:

```
## by social group
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))  ## set par
boxplot(Absenteeism.time.in.hours ~ Social.smoker, dat)
boxplot(Absenteeism.time.in.hours ~ Social.drinker, dat)
par(op)  ## reset par
```

[image]

```
## by social group in one panel 
datl <- reshape(dat, varying=2:3, direction="long")
boxplot(Absenteeism.time.in.hours ~ time + Social, datl)
```

[image]

```
## social group interaction
boxplot(Absenteeism.time.in.hours ~ ., dat)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text="   Absenteeism.time.in.hours Social.smoker Social.drinker
1                          4             0              1
2                          0             0              1
3                          2             0              1
4                          4             1              1
5                          2             0              1
6                          2             0              1
7                          8             0              1
8                          4             0              1
9                         40             0              1
10                         8             0              0
11                         8             0              1
12                         8             0              1
13                         8             0              1
14                         1             0              1
15                         4             0              1
16                         8             0              1
17                         2             0              1
18                         8             1              1
19                         8             0              0
20                         2             1              0")
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @jay.sf is fantastic (and I believe he would be the only one who would survive with amazing visualizations in a world without `ggplot2`). As mentioned by the great @r2evans in comments the key to get `ggplot2` working is reshaping the data. One approach is using `reshape2` functions as you did. But with actual `tidyverse` functions is easier to connect the data analysis pipeline into visual outputs directly. Here I will include an approach using `tidyverse` to reshape data to long with `pivot_wider()` and setting the plot with `ggplot2`. If you want multiple plots you can use `facet_wrap()` in order to give a matrix style for your plot. Here the code where the variable `Absenteeism.time.in.hours` was used as key in order to reshape the other binary variables:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
dat %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Absenteeism.time.in.hours) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=factor(value),y=Absenteeism.time.in.hours))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free')+
    theme_bw()+
    xlab('Var')
```

Output:

[image]

This code was produced thanks to data `dat` processed by @jay.sf (all credits for data management to him).

Comment: Many thanks. @jay.sf, your solution are well done. Really appreciate it! Solution #1 I got the same result, #2 different even I use the same code.

Comment: Many thanks. @Duck your solution are well done. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Annaavaya Awesome, I hope codes here in both solutions are helpful for you :)